# error when try to open route without parameter in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, route-parameters

I have a problem when trying to access any route without parameter:

When I wrte any route without {uname} parameter like this or any other one:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
```

show me this error :
[image]

and it is in the home in another controller?

These is my routes:

```
Route::get('/{uname?}', [HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('home');

Route::get('/info/{uname?}', [HomeController::class, 'info'])->name('info.me');

Route::get('/skills/{uname?}', [HomeController::class, 'skills'])->name('skills');

Route::get('/education/{uname?}', [HomeController::class, 'education'])->name('education');

Route::get('/achievements/{uname?}', [HomeController::class, 'achievements'])->name('achievements');

Route::get('/services/{uname?}', [HomeController::class, 'services'])->name('services');

Route::get('/contact/{uname?}', [HomeController::class, 'contact'])->name('contact');

Route::post('/send-email', [HomeController::class, 'sendEmail'])->name('send-email');

    Route::get('/dashboard/index', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard.index');
    Route::resource('/dashboard/about', AboutController::class);
    Route::resource('/dashboard/skills', SkillsController::class);
    Route::resource('/dashboard/education', EducationController::class);
```

and here is my HomeController:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    function home($uname) {
       $user = User::where('name', '=', $uname)->first();
       $about =  $user->about;
        return view('home', compact('user', 'about'));
    }


    function info($uname) {
        $user = User::where('name', '=', $uname)->first();
        $about =  $user->about;
        return view('info', compact(['user', 'about']));
    }

    function skills($uname) {
        $user = User::where('name', '=', $uname)->first();
        $about = $user->about;
        $skills = $user->skills;
        return view('skills', compact(['skills', 'user', 'about']));
    }
```

I have already tried those and nothing changed:

```
PHP artisan route: cache
PHP artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: `Route::get('/{uname?}',` probably needs to be your last route as it's a catch-all type.

Comment: you have any information why this happened, because before there were no problem, I just add parameter and the problem appeared? by the way it is correct , and just make it as answer and I will accept it

Comment: Your error on line 13 HomeController... can't find user with your condition...., you can change first() to firstOrFaill() method

Comment: @AliSSN, thanks, worked, an also it is work when I add the home route at the end

Comment: @AliSSN , add it as an answer

Comment: @OsamaMohammed, also you can check isset parameters before getting user... if ( isset($uname)){ //do something} else{ //do else something}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your home route is a catch-all route as you have an optional parameter right after your first dash (`/`). This will always catch first and stop any other routes from running because it will always match your current url. To solve this you need to put this kind of route as your last route.

As for your error it's because your not finding any user. If `->first()` doesn't find a matching row it will return `null`, and if it's null you will get an error if you're treating it as an object. You either need to check if `$user` is `null` and set `$about` based on that or use `firstOrFail` and then create a response for that error.

Answer (score 1):

Your error on line 13 of HomeController...
can't find user with your condition and return null and you in line 14 want get about from null....

you have to choose :

**1 :**

```
  function home($uname) {
       $user  =  User::where('name', '=', $uname)->first();
       $about =  $user->about ?? null ;
        return view('home', compact('user', 'about'));
    }
```

**2:**

```
  function home($uname) {
       $user=$about=null;
       if(isset($uname)){
           $user  =  User::where('name', '=', $uname)->first();
           $about =  $user->about ?? null ;
       }
        return view('home', compact('user', 'about'));
    }
```

also you can change first() to firstOrFaill() in first method to get 404 page

Answer (score 0):

$uname is an optional parameter. When it's not available no user could be found. You should check if $user is not null and return an error page or something like that, when $user is null.

```
if ($user !== null) {
    $about =  $user->about;
    return view('home', compact('user', 'about'));
} else {
    return view('error');
}
```

Comment: but i don't use this route, why I find error related with home? for example I use login route?

Comment: Did you define the login route? I can't see it. Looks like this route matches:
Route::get('/{uname?}', [HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('home');

Comment: Laravel default auth routes require Auth::routes(); in the defined routes.